# How to get a String from Android HTTP post request?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I am sending `HTTP post` request to a web server for **login**.It returns string value `true` or `false`. 
 `AsyncTask` code :

```
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String paramUsername = params[0];
        String paramPassword = params[1];


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("myurl");

        try {


        BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("user", paramUsername);
        BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("password", paramPassword);


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
        nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);


            UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

            httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);


            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);

            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);

            }




        return httpResponse.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        String s="true";
        if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrats! Login Successful...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(SignIn.this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username or Password...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

`OnCreate` code:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserNameToLogin);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordToLogin);

    Button btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignIn);
    // btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonSignIn) {
                String givenUsername = editTextUserName.getEditableText().toString();
                String givenPassword = editTextPassword.getEditableText().toString();

           //     System.out.println("Given username :" + givenUsername + " Given password :" + givenPassword);
            new SendPostReqAsyncTask().execute(givenUsername, givenPassword); } }); }
```

Changing the return value of `doInBackground` to `httpResponse.toString()` also causes the app to crash.
I am new to Android, and can't seem to figure out the problem even after much searching. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: The httpResponse can be converted to string by doing the following :

```
String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

Comment: What you return from doInBackground, is what you receive in onPostExecute as a paramater. In your case you are returning null.  Tip: Use retrofit for REST API requests, it's much easier.

Comment: try this one `editTextUserName.getText()`

Comment: You are returning null from doInBackground to onPostExecute that's why it gives NPE at result.equalsIgnoreCase(s)

Comment: `onPostExecute` your `result` values is **null**. Can you say line number of the crash.

Comment: But you return null in doInBackground method and your code is incomplete

Comment: even on changing the return value to httpResponse.toString() gives an error.

Comment: i post answer please use that and than after check

Comment: @VrindaBhatia convert `httpResponse` to string  like my below answer.

Comment: @VrindaBhatia You got the solution.

Answer (score 3):

First Covert your HTTPResponse to String.

```
class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    String result 

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String paramUsername = params[0];
        String paramPassword = params[1];

     try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("Your URL");
        BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("user", paramUsername);
        BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("password", paramPassword);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
        nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

        httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        //From here to Convert from HTTPResponse to String
        result= EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);

        }
 return result;
}
```

Comment: Still an error in line 
 in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));
Log:
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at net.delhi.one97.vrindabhatia.wave2.SignIn$SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(SignIn.java:184)
            at net.delhi.one97.vrindabhatia.wave2.SignIn$SendPostReqAsyncTask.doInBackground(SignIn.java:142)`

Comment: @VrindaBhatia is it possible to give your link.

Comment: the response is not JSON, it just returns a string - either 'true' or 'false'. 
Giving link is not possible as I am developing this app for  company's existing website and link is of their localhost. Do you think there is problem with the link and i should inquire with them again?

Comment: @VrindaBhatia okay.Just sec.when you run the Link in browser.What you exactly get.Just a text like true or false only.

Comment: @VrindaBhatia we can read the Text file.I want know how the output exactly come.

Comment: Yes, I get true or false only. Thank you, adding  
    
            `String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());`
did the trick!

Comment: @VrindaBhatia Nice!.Edit my answer, how you done.It will help some one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading response from server and returning null from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()`. You need to read input stream from httpresponse like this:

```
String result = "";
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
if (inputStream != null) {
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
     String line = "";
     while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
          result += line;
     inputStream.close();
     bufferedReader.close();
}
```

now you can return `result` from `doInbackground()`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to request

```
public String request(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httpPost.setHeader("encytype", "multipart/form-data");

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Buffer Error" + "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you are getting response or not using Log.d as below:

```
httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
Log.d("Response","Response from http:"+response);
```

Check in Logcat what it is showing in place of response. If it is displaying nothing then there are two possibilities. One is server side response is not sending correctly. Second is may be network problem or url not correct. Please check that and let me know. Also show the logcat output if possible.