# Android Login using Httpclient

Tags: php, android, mysql, httpclient

i am newbie in android application for using php, json, mysql and httpclient.
i am trying to make a register and login application. in Register, have successfully. but when login i have a problem. every input email and password always give an error "Invalid email or password". Even i was input a right email and password. the code is below.

login1.php

```
<?php
define('HOST','mxxxx.xxxxx.com');
define('USER','xxxxxx');
define('PASS','xxxxx');
define('DB','xxxxxx');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$emailAddress = $_POST['email'];
$passWord = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "select * from user where email='$emailAddress' and password='$passWord'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$check = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($check)){
echo 'success';
}else{
echo 'failure';
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

then the LoginActivity.class (in eclipse)

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

    public static final String KEY_EMAIL="emailAddress";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD="passWord";

    private EditText etPassword, etEmail;
    String passWord,emailAddress,email;
    Button login;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);
        etEmail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_email);
        etPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_password);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //fullName= etFullName.getText().toString();
                passWord=etPassword.getText().toString();
                emailAddress=etEmail.getText().toString();

                if (!isValidEmail(emailAddress)) {
                    etEmail.setError("Please Enter Valid Email");
                    etEmail.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (!isValidPassword(passWord)){
                    etPassword.setError("Password min. 6 characters");
                    etPassword.requestFocus();
                }else{

                    //new LoginAsync().execute(emailAddress,passWord);

                    login(emailAddress,passWord);
                    // new BackgroundTaskLogin(LoginActivity.this).execute(emailAddress,passWord );
                      etEmail.setText("");
                      etPassword.setText("");
                }

            }
    });
        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

   private void login(final String emailAddress, final String passWord) {
     class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
         //private Context context;
            public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String emailAddress = params[0];
                String passWord = params[1];

                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailAddress));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passWord));
                //return nameValuePairs;

                String result = null;

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx.com/login1.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                String s = result.trim();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ActivityUserProfile.class);
                    intent.putExtra(KEY_EMAIL, emailAddress);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }else {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Email or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }}
        }

     new LoginAsync().execute(emailAddress, passWord);

    }


    private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    // validating password with retype password
    private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
        if (pass != null && pass.length() >= 6) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

        }
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Did you try to log the values that you are passing as parameters while making the login service call ? if not then please check whether they are passing correct values ?

Comment: could you please for helping me, how to make it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(body, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

or

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://someurl.com");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

[Refer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322002/how-to-send-string-by-http-post-in-utf-8)

[Refer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025875/how-to-get-a-string-from-android-http-post-request)

Comment: still the same output @Karthik